# Regex replace in capture group

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a snippet of text from EDI X12. I am trying to find lines where a `BBQ` segment is followed by another `BBQ` segment. I want to replace all `BBQ` segments in the second line with `BBB`

Orig text

```
HI*BBR<0Y6D0Z1<D8<20190816~
HI*BBQ<05BC0ZZ<D8<20190806*BBQ<05BB0ZZ<D8<20190729*BBQ<06UM07Z<D8<20190729~
HI*BBQ<0JBL0ZZ<D8<20190809*BBQ<0J9N0ZZ<D8<20190816*BBQ<0KBS0ZZ<D8<20190816~
HI*BI<71<RD8<20190716-20190722~
```

Needs to become

```
HI*BBR<0Y6D0Z1<D8<20190816~
HI*BBQ<05BC0ZZ<D8<20190806*BBQ<05BB0ZZ<D8<20190729*BBQ<06UM07Z<D8<20190729~
HI*BBB<0JBL0ZZ<D8<20190809*BBB<0J9N0ZZ<D8<20190816*BBB<0KBS0ZZ<D8<20190816~
HI*BI<71<RD8<20190716-20190722~
```

This targets what I am looking for in capturing group 3, but how to replace `BBQ` with `BBB` within that group?

```
(^HI\*BBQ.+?~\r\n)(^HI\*)(BBQ.+?~\r\n)
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Put `BBQ` in its own capture group `(^HI\*)(BBQ)(.+?~\r\n)(^HI\*)(BBQ)(.+?~\r\n)` and replace with `$1BBQ$3$4BBB$6`

Comment: Does it matter where `BBQ` is placed in the string or anywhere in the string twice counts? What about if `BBQ` randomly (and maybe unluckily) is found in the `0JBL0ZZ` strings, do you still want to catch it? Do you want to match every second line (so if the `BBQ` line showed up 4 times, it would replace lines 2 and 4, or just the second line?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, this is a good thought, but with these X12 files you never know how many BBQ segments you will get. In this example I have 6, but a 'real world' file can have up to 24, so I need it to be a bit more dynamic.

Comment: @ctwheels I should never get more than 2 BBQ lines in X12 in a row. I am looking to replace any occurance of BBQ in the second line with BBB. It is not expected in the  0JBL0ZZ strings... but a very good point i need to look into!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:^HI\*BBQ\b.+?~\RHI\*BB|\G(?!^).*?\bBB)\KQ\b`
- Replace with: `B`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
^           # begining of line
  HI\*BBQ   # literally
  .+?       # 1 or more any character but newline
  ~         # a tilde
  \R        # any kind of linebreak
  HI\*BB    # literally
|           # OR
  \G        # restart from last match position
  (?!^)     # not at the beginning of line
  .*?BB     # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy, followed by BB
)           # end group
  \K        # forget all we have seen until this position
  Q         # the letter Q
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: this is close, but I am looking to replace all BBQ on the second line withBBB, not just the first occurance on the second line. FYI thanks for all the detail in your proposal.

Comment: @Toto your edit is much better, but you should add `\b` anchors to ensure it's `BBQ` that's being matched, not some random case of `0JBL0ZZ` having `BBQ` in it, albeit unlikely, still possible.

Comment: Thanks guys! @Toto saved the day. I will need to step through this to fill my knowledge gaps, but this works great. Cheers!